# Change imag src in CSS Element

Tags: html, css, image, src

I am having trouble changing the src img of an Element. Basically I have a custom CSS script and need to change a logo image. Below is the source code:

[image]

I am trying to change the div alt="logo" src.

So far I have the following, but it is now working:

```
#wrapper-login .login {
    img src="/MyDevice/images/login/new_logo.png"
}
```

Can someone help point out where I am going wrong please?

Many Thanks!

Comment: CSS is not a script. I does nothing. Browser use it to style elements not change them.

Comment: `src` is not a style attribute, you can't change it like that!

Comment: You could set `background-image: url('../new_logo.png');` in CSS.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot change the HTML with CSS, only how it is rendered. Use JavaScript instead.

```
document.querySelector("#wrapper-login .login").src = "/MyDevice/images/login/new_logo.png";
```

Or, for better browser support:

```
document.getElementById("#wrapper-login").getElementsByClassName(".login")[0].src = "/MyDevice/images/login/new_logo.png";
```